# Rails routing acts weirdly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Suddenly my Rails application acts weirdly. If I attach an image on a edit page and submit the form, `show` action is called instead of update action. If I don't attach any image, it's ok.

#### Routes

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :products do
    collection do
      get :download_images
      get :all_styles
      post :compress_images
    end
  end
end
```

#### View

```
%h1 Edit Product

= form_for [:admin, @product], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  - if f.object.accessory?
    = render 'form_accessory', :f => f
  - else
    = render 'form', :f => f

[_form partial]
:javascript
  function exclusiveCheck(check_box) {
    if (check_box.checked) {
      $('#pictures_fieldset .is_main').attr('checked', false);
      check_box.checked = true;
    }
  }
- error_messages_for f.object

%fieldset.span-23
  %legend
  .row
    = f.label :category_id, :class => "required"
    %br
    = f.select :category_id, array_of_categories('garment'), :include_blank => true
    = f.check_box :new_in_category
    = image_tag "new_icon.png"

  .row
    = f.label :style_no, :class => "required"
    %br
    = f.text_field :style_no, :style => "width: 5em;"

  .row
    = f.label :name, :class => "required"
    %br
    = f.text_field :name

  .row
    = f.label :fabric_info, :class => ""
    %br
    = f.text_field :fabric_info, :style => "width: 90%;"

  .row
    = f.label :lb_per_piece, "Weight", :class => "required"
    %br
    = f.text_field :lb_per_piece, :style => "width: 3em;"

  .row
    .span-3
      = f.label :price, :class => "required"
      %br
      = f.text_field :price, :style => "width: 6em;"
    .span-3
      = f.label :original_price, :class => ""
      %br
      = f.text_field :original_price, :style => "width: 6em;"
    .span-10
      %label Discount Rate
      %br
      = text_field_tag :percent, nil, :style => "width: 3em;", :id => "percent"
      = "%"
      = link_to_function "Set", "setPrice();"
      = f.check_box :new_in_sale
      = image_tag "new_icon.png"
  .row
    = f.label :video, :class => ""
    %br
    = f.text_field :video, :style => "width: 15em;"
    (Upload videos to data.ohyesfashion.com at ~/files/videos directory.)

  .row
    = f.label :available_on
    %br
    = f.text_field :available_on, :class => 'date'

  .row
    = f.check_box :active
    = f.label :active, :class => ""

  .row
    = f.check_box :new_arrival
    = f.label :new_arrival, :class => ""
    = f.check_box :new_in_new_arrival?
    = image_tag "new_icon.png"

  .row
    = f.check_box :best
    = f.label :best, :class => ""
    = f.check_box :new_in_best
    = image_tag "new_icon.png"
.span-24.last
  %button.button.positive(type="submit")
    = icon_for(:accept, "Save")

%fieldset
  %legend Sizes
  - Product::SIZES.each do |size|
    .span-2
      = size.to_s.upcase
      = f.select size, [*0..20].map { |i| i.to_s }

.span-24
  .span-12
    %fieldset
      %legend Descriptions
      - Description.order("code, name").each do |description|
        .row
          = check_box_tag "descriptions[]", description.id, f.object.descriptions.include?(description)
          = "[#{description.code}]"
          = description.name
      .row
        New Description 
        = text_field_tag :new_description_name
  .span-12.last
    %fieldset(style="float: right;")
      %legend Colors
      .span-11
      - Color.order("name").each do |color|
        .row
          .span-1
            = check_box_tag "colors[]", color.id, f.object.colors.include?(color)
          .span-4
            = color_box color
          .span-3
            = check_box_tag "sold_out_colors[]", color.id, (f.object.colors.include?(color) and Colorship.sold_out?(f.object, color))
            Sold Out
          .span-2
            = check_box_tag "is_new_colors[]", color.id, (f.object.colors.include?(color) and Colorship.is_new?(f.object, color))
            New

.span-24.last
  %button.button.positive(type="submit")
    = icon_for(:accept, "Save")


- (15 - f.object.pictures.size).times { f.object.pictures.build }
%fieldset#pictures_fieldset
  %legend Images
  .row
    = f.label :model_id, "Model"
    = f.select :model_id, PhotoModel.all.map { |i| [i.name, i.id] }, :include_blank => true
  %br
  = f.fields_for :pictures do |ff|
    .span-7(style="height: 150px;")
      - if ff.object.new_record?
        = ff.file_field :image
      - else
        = image_tag ff.object.image.url(:w45)
        %br
        = ff.object.image_file_name
        %br
        = ff.check_box :is_main, :onclick => "exclusiveCheck(this)", :class => "is_main"
        Title
        %br
        = ff.check_box "_destroy"
        Delete


.span-24.last
  = link_to icon_for(:back, "Back"), :back, :class => "button negative"
  %button.button.positive(type="submit")
    = icon_for(:accept, "Save")

:javascript

  function setPrice() {
    if ($('#product_original_price').val() != '' && $('#percent').val() != '') {
      var originalPrice = parseFloat($('#product_original_price').val());
      var percent = parseFloat($('#percent').val());
      $('#product_price').val(originalPrice * (100 - percent) / 100.0);
    }
  }
```

Any idea what's going on? It used to work fine.

Comment: show action is called instead of show action? o_O

Comment: Oops. It should be "instead of update action". Edited.

Comment: Can you post the view code that generates the form? Also, what have you changed lately that could've caused this new behavior?

Comment: Brandan, I added the view code. I guess the code is ok as it works on my dev machine. The problem happens only on production server. It used to work fine on the production server until yesterday.

Comment: Never mind. I rebooted my VPS(Virtual Private Server) and everything's fine now.

Comment: I guess the problem was passenger. One thing I noticed weird was that when I first found the problem, locale=koyqxapskb param was there and it followed later urls. I had to change it to locale=en. Weird.

Comment: Also, when the problem started, /tmp directory was full and I had to delete all the files there. Probably that caused the problem.